# Caliburn - PropertyChanged for child ViewModel

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, caliburn

I'm using Caliburn and the MVVM pattern in a WPF application, and am trying to use as many conventions as possible.  One issue I'm running into is when I have to wire-up some property-changed notifications on an imported class.

Say I have a ViewModel like so:

```
class ViewModelA
{
    private readonly IViewModelB _b;

    public ViewModelA(IViewModelB b)
    {
        _b = b;
    }

    public bool CanGo
    {
        get { return _b.MyBoolProperty; }
    }

    public void Go()
    {
        //Does something here
    }
}
```

What is the recommended (correct) way to call NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => CanGo) when the PropertyChanged event for MyBoolProperty is fired off ViewModelB?

In the past I've used a PropertyObserver type class to manage this.

Or am I designing this scenario completely wrong?

Comment: I've found the AutoCheckAvailabilityAttribute can make this work by relying on the CommandManager input system.  However, I think this option would call my CanGo method more than I'd like.  How can I do this with the DependenciesAttribute?  I can't seem to figure out how to make it work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your "sub"-model is exposed with a public property, you could use DependenciesAttribute to track changes:

```
 
class ViewModelA
{
    public IViewModelB B {get; private set;}

    public ViewModelA(IViewModelB b)
    {
        B = b;
    }

    public bool CanGo
    {
        get { return B.MyBoolProperty; }
    }

    [Dependencies("B.MyBoolProperty")]
    public void Go()
    {
        //Does something here
    }
}
```

To work properly, the whole property path should be composed of notifying objects.
You can also put a final "*"

```
[Dependencies("B.*")]
```

to indicate that all properties of B should cause the precondition re-evaluation; note that "*" only acts on the end of the proprerty path and just for *one* level of depth (it doesn't track changes on sub-models of B).

Comment: The "." syntax is what I was missing and knowing to put this on the method, not the CanX property.  I could not find an example of using this anywhere, thanks.